# Closed (compact) Matrix group with algebraic entries is discrete (finite)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $ H $ be a compact subgroup of $ GL_n(\mathbb{C}) $. Suppose that every matrix in the subgroup $ H $ has algebraic matrix entries. Can we conclude that $ H $ is finite?

I know that any representation of a finite group has algebraic matrix entries. The question I'm asking is a sort of converse to this: do ( compact ) matrix groups with algebraic entries have to be finite?

I am also curious if in general any closed subgroup $ H $ of $ GL_n(\mathbb{C}) $ with all  entries algebraic must be discrete. (Certainly once we weaken the assumption on the subgroup from compact to closed it does not have to be finite anymore, take for example the closed subgroup with algebraic matrix entries $ H =\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}: n \in \mathbb{Z}\right \} $ )

Comment: If $H$ is infinite, it is nondiscrete, hence it is (infinite) perfect, hence, uncountable, so...

Comment: Quick note:  Representations of finite G do *not* need to have algebraic entries, they only need to be conjugate to a matrix with algebraic entries.

Comment: @MoisheKohan so if I understand your argument correctly if we suppose for a contradiction that $ H $ is not discrete then some point is a limit point but then by homogeneity every point is a limit point so $ H $ is perfect set (since it is also closed) but a perfect set contains an embedded cantor set and this is uncountable contradicting the assumption that $ H $ is contained in the countable group $ GL_n( \overline{\mathbb{Q}}) $

Comment: Yep.............